# Using Watin to log into chase website

Tags: c#, watin

I am trying to automate paying bills so I want to automatically login to some websites find what I owe and then pay them using bill pay.

I am using Watin

Here is my Code:

```
            var browser = new IE("http://www.chase.com")
            browser.TextField(Find.ById("usr_name")).TypeText("none");
            browser.TextField(Find.ById("usr_password")).TypeText("none");
            browser.Button(Find.ByAlt("log on")).Click();
```

I am trying to find the button to click, but I Don't know how to do it since it isn't just a name.

Comment: Does watin have a Find.ByCssSelector method? I know WebDriver does. In WebDriver we would just do browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#logonform input[type=image]"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to find the form and submit it:

```
browser.Form(Find.ById("logonform")).Submit();
```